# Why does a LIMIT 1 return another result that a standard select with ordering?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I have a MariaDB database table which holds employeeNumber (PK), firstName, LastName and email.
I have several records in there (see at the end of the question).
When I do `SELECT employeeNumber,lastName,firstName,email FROM employees ORDER BY lastName;` it returns 1337 Bondur Loui as first result, though I think it should be 1102 Bondur Gerard. When I add a `LIMIT 1` it suddenly works correctly: it returns Gerard. When I do `LIMIT 2`, it again select  the right choice: Gerard.

Why does an order by lastName without limit return Loui while with limit it returns Gerard?

The existing records:

```
+----------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------+                                                                           
      
| employeeNumber | firstName | lastName  | email                           |                                                                           
      
+----------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------+                                                                           
      
|           1002 | Diane     | Murphy    | dmurphy@classicmodelcars.com    |                                                                           
      
|           1056 | Mary      | Patterson | mpatterso@classicmodelcars.com  |                                                                           
      
|           1076 | Jeff      | Firrelli  | jfirrelli@classicmodelcars.com  |                                                                           
      
|           1088 | William   | Patterson | wpatterson@classicmodelcars.com |                                                                           
      
|           1102 | Gerard    | Bondur    | gbondur@classicmodelcars.com    |                                                                           
      
|           1143 | Anthony   | Bow       | abow@classicmodelcars.com       |                                                                           
      
|           1165 | Leslie    | Jennings  | ljennings@classicmodelcars.com  |                                                                           
      
|           1166 | Leslie    | Thompson  | lthompson@classicmodelcars.com  |                                                                           
      
|           1188 | Julie     | Firrelli  | jfirrelli@classicmodelcars.com  |                                                                           
      
|           1216 | Steve     | Patterson | spatterson@classicmodelcars.com |                                                                           
      
|           1286 | Foon Yue  | Tseng     | ftseng@classicmodelcars.com     |                                                                           
      
|           1323 | George    | Vanauf    | gvanauf@classicmodelcars.com    |                                                                           
      
|           1337 | Loui      | Bondur    | lbondur@classicmodelcars.com    |                                                                           
      
|           1370 | Gerard    | Hernandez | ghernande@classicmodelcars.com  |                                                                           
      
|           1401 | Pamela    | Castillo  | pcastillo@classicmodelcars.com  |                                                                           
      
|           1501 | Larry     | Bott      | lbott@classicmodelcars.com      |                                                                           
      
|           1504 | Barry     | Jones     | bjones@classicmodelcars.com     |                                                                           
      
|           1611 | Andy      | Fixter    | afixter@classicmodelcars.com    |                                                                           
      
|           1612 | Peter     | Marsh     | pmarsh@classicmodelcars.com     |                                                                           
      
|           1619 | Tom       | King      | tking@classicmodelcars.com      |                                                                           
      
|           1621 | Mami      | Nishi     | mnishi@classicmodelcars.com     |                                                                           
      
|           1625 | Yoshimi   | Kato      | ykato@classicmodelcars.com      |                                                                           
      
|           1702 | Martin    | Gerard    | mgerard@classicmodelcars.com    |                                                                           
      
+----------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------+                                                                           
      
23 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: If you order by last name only and multiple rows have the identic last name, your DBMS will sort by last name only and decide on its own how to "sort" those rows having the same last name. If you want to apply a further order, you need to extend your order by clause, for example by adding the first name. Then the result will be first sorted by last name and if they are identic then by first name. By the way, I can't reproduce your description: https://dbfiddle.uk/7sHe4BxJ But even If you would know why/how the DBMS takes it own decisions, this won't help you. Just use a correct order by.

Comment: any time your order by does not fully distinguish between different rows, you will get arbitrary order of the rows (though respecting the order by critiera you did supply).  ideally always write your queries to never get arbitrary results, so `order by lastName, firstName, employeeNumber` or similar, making sure to include the primary key if you haven't specified enough to guarantee uniqueness